# R: Interpolation between raster layers of different dates

Tags: r, time-series, interpolation, raster

Let's say I have 4 raster layers with the same extend with data of 4 different years: 2006,2008,2010 and 2012:

```
library(raster)

r2006<-raster(ncol=3, nrow=3)
values(r2006)<-1:9

r2008<-raster(ncol=3, nrow=3)
values(r2008)<-3:11

r2010<-raster(ncol=3, nrow=3)
values(r2010)<-5:13

r2012<-raster(ncol=3, nrow=3)
values(r2012)<-7:15
```

Now I want to create raster layers for every year between 2006 and 2013 (or even longer) by inter-/extrapolating (a linear method should be a good start) the values of the 4 raster layers. The result should look like this:

```
r2006<-raster(ncol=3, nrow=3)
values(r2006)<-1:9

r2007<-raster(ncol=3, nrow=3)
values(r2007)<-2:10

r2008<-raster(ncol=3, nrow=3)
values(r2008)<-3:11

r2009<-raster(ncol=3, nrow=3)
values(r2009)<-4:12

r2010<-raster(ncol=3, nrow=3)
values(r2010)<-5:13

r2011<-raster(ncol=3, nrow=3)
values(r2011)<-6:14

r2012<-raster(ncol=3, nrow=3)
values(r2012)<-7:15

r2013<-raster(ncol=3, nrow=3)
values(r2013)<-8:16
```

Using `lm()` or `approxExtrap` don't seem to help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to separate your problem into two parts: 1. First, perform the numerical interpolation on the raster values, 2. and apply the interpolated values to the appropriate intermediate raster layers.

**Idea**: Build a data frame of the values() of the raster layers, time index that data frame, and then apply Linear Interpolation to those numbers. For linear interpolation I use `approxTime` from the `simecol` package.

For your example above,

```
library(raster)
library(simecol)    
df <- data.frame("2006" = 1:9, "2008" = 3:11, "2010" = 5:13, "2012"=7:15)

#transpose since we want time to be the first col, and the values to be columns
new <- data.frame(t(df))
times <- seq(2006, 2012, by=2)
new <- cbind(times, new)

# Now, apply Linear Interpolate for each layer of the raster
approxTime(new, 2006:2012, rule = 2)
```

This gives:

```
#  times X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9
#1  2006  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
#2  2007  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
#3  2008  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
#4  2009  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
#5  2010  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
#6  2011  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
#7  2012  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

You can then store this, and take each row and apply to the values of that year's raster object.

Note: approxTime does not do linear *extrapolation*. It simply takes the closest value, so you need to account for that.

Comment: This works for linear interpolation, if you don't have any NA's in your dataset. My solution for having NA's, which `approxTime` can't handle: just change all NA to a number you don't have in your dataset (e.g. 0) with `is.na`, do the _interpolation_ and change the number back to NA afterwards.

Comment: good solution for interpolation. I tried the same code with `approxExtrap` from the `Hmisc` package, but I just get a `list` with 2 components: one with the inter- and extrapolated years and one just filled with 0's. This is strange as both `approxTime` and `approxExtrap` seem to base on `approxfun`. Any ideas on that @Ram Narasimhan?