# Interpolating large raster series in R

Tags: r, interpolation, raster, r-raster

I have 36ish years of gridded/raster monthly temperature estimates that I'd like to convert into daily estimates. For now, I'm setting the monthly estimates at the midpoint of the month and doing a simple linear interpolation. To do so, I'm attempting to use the raster::calc and stats::approx described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352251/gap-filling-temporal-raster-objects/33352466). However, in doing so, I get the following error:

> Error in is.infinite(v) : default method not implemented for type 'list'

Below is some code that hopefully provides a simulation of sorts to recreate the problem. I think the problem is how NA's are dealt with because the `q_interp` bit at the end (where no rasters are set to NA). That said, I'm not really sure what to do with this information.

```
library(raster)

#The parameters of the problem
num_days = 9861
months_num = 324
num_na = 191780

#generate baseline rasters
r <- raster(nrows=360, ncols=720); 
values(r) <- NA
x <- sapply(1:months_num, function(...) setValues(r, runif(ncell(r))))

#make them a stack
s = stack(x)

#define what x coordinates the rasters refer to (e.g. loosely convert monthly to daily). Probably not the most elegant solution in the world.
num_day_month = c(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31)
days = as.character(seq(as.Date('1989/01/01'), as.Date('2015/12/31'), by = 'day'))
months = as.character(seq(as.Date('1989/01/01'), as.Date('2015/12/01'), by = 'month'))
months = substr(months, 1,nchar(months)-3)
mid_points = as.vector(lapply(months, function(x) grep(x,days,value =T)[round(length(grep(x,days,value =T))/2)]))
mp_loc = days %in% mid_points
#output is the monthly mid points on the daily scale
mp_day_locs = (1:length(days))[mp_loc]

#make some of the cells NA throughout the whole span. In the actual dataset, the NAs generally represent oceans.
s[sample(ncell(s), num_na)] = NA

#a function to interpolate
interp_row <- function(base_indexes, value_vector, return_indexes, rule_num =2) {
  nnn = length(value_vector)
  if (any(is.na(value_vector))) {
    return(rep(NA, nnn))
  } else {
    return(approx(x = base_indexes, y= value_vector, xout = return_indexes, rule=rule_num)$y)
  }
}

#this is the function call that causes the error to be thrown
s_interp = calc(s, function(y) interp_row(base_indexes = mp_day_locs, value_vector = y, return_indexes = 1:length(days),rule_num = 2))

#Now make a without NAs-- seems to work
#generate baseline rasters
r <- raster(nrows=360, ncols=720); 
values(r) <- NA
x <- sapply(1:months_num, function(...) setValues(r, runif(ncell(r))))
#make them a stack
q = stack(x)
q_interp = calc(q, function(y) interp_row(base_indexes = mp_day_locs, value_vector = y, return_indexes = 1:length(days),rule_num = 2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (as far as I can see) is the length of return vector created if any value is NA. In your case its length is the same as the input vector:

```
# length = 324
nnn = length(value_vector)
return(rep(NA, nnn))
```

However the return vector created in the correct case (without NA) is much longer (daily values):

```
#length = 9861
return(approx(x = base_indexes, y= value_vector, xout = return_indexes, rule=rule_num)$y)
```

As far as I know, the two return cases need to have the same lenght. Try to change your function as follows by setting `rep(NA, length(return_indexes))` :

```
interp_row <- function(base_indexes, value_vector, return_indexes, rule_num =2) {
  nnn = length(value_vector)
  if (any(is.na(value_vector))) {
    return(rep(NA, length(return_indexes)))
  } else {
    return(approx(x = base_indexes, y= value_vector, xout = return_indexes, rule=rule_num)$y)
  }
}
```

**Note:** Your code seems to be quite slow. One quick solution is to use the `clusterR()` function to speed up your code. This function enables the use of multicore processing of some raster functions like `calc`. Type `?clusterR` or have a look [here](http://www.gis-blog.com/increasing-the-speed-of-raster-processing-with-r-part-33-cluster/).